# ID number entry once per Day

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to create a query that allows the ID number to enter in mysql once per day?

I just wanted to know if is it possible to have that query which the ID number allows to enter once per day and it will be accept again after 24hrs of entering the database.

And how it will be inserted to another table in my database.

I have 2 tables:
emp_list > emp_id, emp_name, reg_date
ticket_logs > emp_id, datelogs

I really bad at constructing English sentences. I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say.

```
$check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM emp_lists WHERE emp_id='$emp_id'");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
$query = "INSERT INTO ticket_logs (id, emp_id) SELECT id, emp_id FROM emp_lists WHERE emp_id='$emp_id'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($checkrows != null) {
    echo "";
} else {  
    //insert results from the input
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO ticket_logs(emp_id) VALUES('$emp_id')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('<span style="color:#fa0a0a;text-align:center;">Invalid ID Number!</span>');
    mysqli_close($con);
}
echo'<span style="color:#0d02db;text-align:center;">ID Number Accepted! For Today Please Return after 24hours, Thank you!</span>';
};
```

Comment: You could have a compound index and make it unique. This SQL is not secure. Parameterize queries and use prepared statements.

Comment: You should use `bind_param()` with `prepare()`, NOT concatenate string like this. To check data in DB use `SELECT` not `INSERT`.

Comment: It is **not** quite clear what your real intention is.

Comment: my system needs to check if the ID number of employee is registered in the database if yes it will store at the ticket_logs as per date the user inputted into the textbox.
I need to store ID number of the employee to ticket_logs with different dates but same ID number inside my db. And also once the ID number has entry for this day it will not be able to enter by the same day, the system will accept again the ID number after 24hours. Hope you guys understands me I'm panicking btw. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, one can choose storing the datetime ( or timestamp ) value into the db table so that the system knows the value of the last data insertion.

Comment: and that's how my system allows to entry ID number then comeback for tomorrow for new entry of existing ID number?

Comment: You just need a single `SELECT` query for checking id & today's date combination; `if` the checking query returned a result, send a message that "it's already there"... `else`, do the `INSERT` query and send the message "ID Number Accepted! For Today Please Return after 24hours, Thank you!". However, I assume that you don't really mean 24 hours, instead the next day/date.

Comment: @FanoFN can you show me the example on how it works? and also I want the ID number to be stored again for 24 hours not next day/date. Thank you so much!

Comment: I never really work with PHP so I only can give idea how it may work. As for the 24 hours checking in MySQL, you can do something like `SELECT * FROM ticket_logs WHERE emp_id=? AND datetime_col <= datetime_col + INTERVAL 24 HOUR;` - if this return result, then you know it's not beyond 24 hours yet therefore you stop the process there. If not, insert the exact datetime with something like `INSERT INTO ticket_logs(emp_id, datetime_col) VALUES (?, NOW())`. That is assuming you have a datetime column (e.g. `datetime_col`) in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add a column in the ticket_logs named say `timestamp` (of type `datetime`) so that the system can check the datetime of inserted records

Then use this data to determine whether to insert data (or not). So if there is NO record of `now() < timestamp + INTERVAL 24 HOUR` , then execute the data insertion, otherwise not to do so.

On the other hand, please change to use parameterized prepared statements so as to avoid SQL inject attacks.

So the code is:

```
<?php
//$emp_id=1234;

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $dbuser, $password, $db);

$query="SELECT * FROM ticket_logs WHERE emp_id=? and now() < timestamp + INTERVAL 24 HOUR";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $emp_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();


if ($result->num_rows==0) {

  $query2="INSERT INTO ticket_logs (emp_id, timestamp) values (?, now())";
  $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($query2);
  $stmt2->bind_param("i", $emp_id);
  $stmt2->execute();

  echo '<span style="color:#0d02db;text-align:center;">ID Number Accepted!</span>';

} else {
  echo '<span style="color:#0d02db;text-align:center;">ID Number Not Accepted! Please Return after 24hours, Thank you!</span>';
}   
?>
```